# Proper way of querying table columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have about 6 tables where some of the columns are identical. Do I have to know which tables contain the column I'm querying on or is there a way to write an SQL query such that I can reference a column and the database will scan the tables looking for a specific column?

For example, assume table1, table3, and table5 all contain the column 'Population'. Do I have to specify in my query that I want to retrieve information from 'Population' in tables table1, table2, and table3, or can is there a way to only specify that I want information from the 'Population' column without specifying any tables?

Comment: Yes, you have to specify the table you want to access the column from. You can create views to simplify querying.

Comment: The engine is not smart enough to know what populations you want so you have to be specific.  Extending your example: lets say table2 also has population but you don't want it.  How would the engine know not to include it?  You must specify `table.field` for the values when duplication occurs.  If a field name only exists in one table, the engine is smart enough to know which table it's in; but from a maintenance standpoint, you really should specify tablename.field or Tablealias.field in the select to aid in maintenance and readability; especially if you have many tables.

Comment: Additionally lets say it did work.  How would you know which population value came from table 1 or 2 or 3?  by being specific you can alias the table.fields so you know from what source table each value came.

Answer (score 1):

```
select table1.population as pop1, table2.population as pop2, table5.population as pop3
from table1, table2, table5;
```

This will return 3 columns showing the population from each table.

```
select population
from table1
union
select population
from table2
union
select population
from table5;
```

This will return a long list of populations in one column.

Comment: The union concept here is good given the known requirements; you may need to add a "Source" Column with the table name to make it a bit more usable.